# Best practices - Declare opengles 2.0 cube vertices

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I've seen a lot of ways to declare the vertices of a cube in space. Some codes declare 36 vertices, some other just eight, like that:

```
private float vertices[] = {
                                -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, //p1 lower left far plane (0)
                                1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,  //p2 lower right far plane (1)
                                1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,  //p3 top right far plane (2)
                                -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,  //p4 top left far plane (3)
                                -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f, //p5 lower left near plane (4)
                                1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,  //p6 lower right near plane (5)
                                1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,  //p7 top right near plane (6)
                                -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f  //p8 top left near plane (7)
                                };
```

It looks like you draw just two faces and then fill the holes.
That seems preferable so I'm saving precious bytes. 
Is that correct? What order shall I specify in the indices array?

---EDIT
Ok, I've got it. This should be the order to declare the vertices, right? But my cube has wrong triangles on some faces.

```
private short order[] = {
                              0, 4, 5, 0, 5, 1, //bottom face
                              1, 5, 6, 1, 6, 2, //right face
                              2, 6, 7, 2, 7, 3, // top face
                              3, 7, 4, 3, 4, 0, // left face
                              4, 7, 6, 4, 6, 5, // front face
                              3, 0, 1, 3, 1, 2 // back face
                              };
```

Comment: The reason some solutions might use more than 8 vertices is if each cube face needs unique colors/normals. Without flat shading+provoking vertices, sharing vertices is going to cause the color/normal for each face to be averaged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that's right. once you define the vertices for the front and back (near and far) faces you have given all the information needed to construct the cube. Anything else is redundant and waste memory.

The only thing you need to be careful about is this : When you actually use the vertices to construct the cube **order matters**.

By default opengl expects for the vertices to be provided counter clockwise. I believe you can override that behavior, but I have spent many hours trying to figure out what I thought were coding mistakes that turned out to be vertex ordering mistakes. As long as you remember to always construct the vertices in the counter clockwise manner (as viewed from the outside of the cube) the rendering should work fine.

Comment: `I believe you can override that behaviour` - [glCullFace](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glCullFace.xml)

Comment: More to the point, you can re-define the face that is considered the front by the rasterizer with `glFrontFace (...)`. The front face affects more than culling, so often times rather than simply culling a different side, it makes more sense to properly define the front. But also, understand that this winding calculation is done in post-projected space. Inverting the Y-axis in the projection matrix, for instance, will reverse polygon winding.

Comment: So, following the method above, shall I use TRIANGLES or TRIANGLES_STRIP?

Comment: Glad to see your enthusiasm for OpenGL. I am assuming that you are new to OpenGL. If I were back in your shoes I would use triangles, render a face and view it, then render another face iteratively so that I could see it working. The other thing that might help you is [NeHe Tutorials](http://nehe.gamedev.net/) they are what many consider to be the definitive beginner's guide and come with code / project files.

Comment: Yes I am new, Clayton. I've finally managed to render properly the cube, but only with triangle_strip. I guess that's the way it is supposed to be, though I've seen examples with TRIANGLES only. But I can't explain why.

Comment: There is no technical reason that you shouldn't be able to render a cube with triangles. I would suggest that you take a look here [NeHe Tutorials 1-5](http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/lessons_01__05/22004/) they are quick and cover everything you need to know in detail.